# MetaIntegrator in R

Tags: r

I want to do integrated two GSE files (geo expression dataset). I am using the MetaIntegrator package..

** The downloaded source packages are in
‘C:\Users\Prachi\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpaEmkMc\downloaded_packages’
Warning messages:
1: package ‘library(MetaIntegrator)’ is not available for this version of R

A version of this package for your version of R might be available elsewhere,
see the ideas at
https://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-patched/R-admin.html#Installing-packages
2: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l, repos = repos,  :
installation of package ‘utf8’ had non-zero exit status
3: In install.packages(update[instlib == l, "Package"], l, repos = repos,  :
installation of package ‘XML’ had non-zero exit status

I also tried to download and install it, but it didn't work

> sessionInfo()
> R version 4.0.3 (2020-10-10)
> Platform: x86_64-w64-mingw32/x64 (64-bit)
> Running under: Windows 10 x64 (build 18363)

Matrix products: default

locale:
[1] LC_COLLATE=English_United States.1252  LC_CTYPE=English_United States.1252
[3] LC_MONETARY=English_United States.1252 LC_NUMERIC=C
[5] LC_TIME=English_United States.1252

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets  methods   base

other attached packages:
[1] RCurl_1.98-1.2        httpuv_1.5.5          plotly_4.9.3          readr_1.4.0
[5] magrittr_2.0.1        HGNChelper_0.8.1      AnnotationDbi_1.52.0  IRanges_2.24.1
[9] S4Vectors_0.28.1      rmarkdown_2.7         reshape2_1.4.4        dplyr_1.0.5
[13] boot_1.3-27           pheatmap_1.0.12       DT_0.17               manhattanly_0.2.0
[17] Metrics_0.1.4         COCONUT_1.0.2         pracma_2.3.3          zoo_1.8-9
[21] ROCR_1.0-11           ggpubr_0.4.0          data.table_1.14.0     GEOmetadb_1.52.0
[25] RSQLite_2.2.3         gplots_3.1.1          ggplot2_3.3.3         multtest_2.46.0
[29] preprocessCore_1.52.1 stringr_1.4.0         RMySQL_0.10.21        DBI_1.1.1
[33] Rmisc_1.5             plyr_1.8.6            lattice_0.20-41       rmeta_3.0
[37] hgu133plus2cdf_2.18.0 affy_1.68.0           GEOquery_2.58.0       Biobase_2.50.0
[41] BiocGenerics_0.36.0

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
[1] colorspace_2.0-0    ggsignif_0.6.1      ellipsis_0.3.1      rio_0.5.26          rstudioapi_0.13
[6] affyio_1.60.0       bit64_4.0.5         fansi_0.4.2         xml2_1.3.2          splines_4.0.3
[11] cachem_1.0.4        knitr_1.31          jsonlite_1.7.2      broom_0.7.5         BiocManager_1.30.10
[16] compiler_4.0.3      httr_1.4.2          backports_1.2.1     assertthat_0.2.1    Matrix_1.3-2
[21] fastmap_1.1.0       lazyeval_0.2.2      limma_3.46.0        cli_2.3.1           later_1.1.0.1
[26] htmltools_0.5.1.1   tools_4.0.3         gtable_0.3.0        glue_1.4.2          tinytex_0.30
[31] Rcpp_1.0.6          carData_3.0-4       cellranger_1.1.0    vctrs_0.3.6         xfun_0.22
[36] openxlsx_4.2.3      lifecycle_1.0.0     pacman_0.5.1        gtools_3.8.2        rstatix_0.7.0
[41] zlibbioc_1.36.0     MASS_7.3-53.1       scales_1.1.1        promises_1.2.0.1    hms_1.0.0
[46] RColorBrewer_1.1-2  curl_4.3            memoise_2.0.0       stringi_1.5.3       caTools_1.18.1
[51] zip_2.1.1           rlang_0.4.10        pkgconfig_2.0.3     bitops_1.0-6        evaluate_0.14
[56] purrr_0.3.4         htmlwidgets_1.5.3   cowplot_1.1.1       bit_4.0.4           tidyselect_1.1.0
[61] R6_2.5.0            generics_0.1.0      pillar_1.5.1        haven_2.3.1         foreign_0.8-81
[66] withr_2.4.1         survival_3.2-10     abind_1.4-7         tibble_3.1.0        crayon_1.4.1
[71] car_3.0-11          KernSmooth_2.23-18  utf8_1.1.4          grid_4.0.3          readxl_1.3.1
[76] blob_1.2.1          forcats_0.5.1       digest_0.6.27       tidyr_1.1.3         munsell_0.5.0
[81] viridisLite_0.3.0

> 

Comment: Welcome. When posting please post the *actual code* that causes an issue and be explicit about the error description. Please also *read the formatting help* when posting to ensure the question is readable. — That said, I’m guessing that you tried to execute `install.packages("library(MetaIntegrator)")`. That’s a typo: what you want is `install.packages("MetaIntegrator")`.

Answer (score 0):

**you can try this,, i installed last week only**

```
  BiocManager::install("MetaIntegrator")
    pacman::p_load(rmeta, multtest, ggplot2, parallel, Rmisc, gplots, Biobase, RMySQL, DBI, stringr, preprocessCore, GEOquery, GEOmetadb, RSQLite, data.table, ggpubr, ROCR, zoo, pracma, COCONUT, Metrics, manhattanly, DT, pheatmap, plyr, boot, dplyr, reshape2, rmarkdown, AnnotationDbi, HGNChelper, magrittr, readr, plotly, httpuv)
    pacman::p_load(TCGAbiolinks,limma,edgeR,glmnet,factoextra,FactoMineR,caret,SummarizedExperiment,gplots,survival,survminer,
                   RColorBrewer,gProfileR,genefilter,miRBaseConverter,enrichR,VennDiagram,GDCRNATools,SpidermiR,DESeq2,clusterProfiler,wordcloud,
                   org.Hs.eg.db,EnhancedVolcano,GEOquery,dplyr)

library(MetaIntegrator)
```